# Fatal exception while collapsing a expandable list in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I was struggling with collapsing a group in expandable list view, the thing i need is, i need to collapse all group except selected group.
I tried below code, its working when current position is less than previous position, in vice-versa i'm getting a fatal exception and also i'm unable to caught it.

```
elv.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

     @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {


          if (lastExpandedGroupPosition != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition) {
            if(lastExpandedGroupPosition>groupPosition){
                  elv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
               }else{
                    Log.v("last expand value", ""+lastExpandedGroupPosition);
                        Log.v("groupPosition", ""+groupPosition);
                        Log.v("count", ""+elv.getCount());

                 elv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);

                    }
                }
               lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: i do not see any stacktrace posted

Comment: post your error logs also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing setOnGroupClickListener to setOnGroupExpandListener

```
 elv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

@Override
public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (lastExpandedGroupPosition != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition) {
           if(lastExpandedGroupPosition>groupPosition){
                  elv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
                    }else{
                    Log.v("last expand value", ""+lastExpandedGroupPosition);
                        Log.v("groupPosition", ""+groupPosition);
                        Log.v("count", ""+elv.getCount());

                     elv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);


                    }
                }
                lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
            }
        });
```